# To avoid SOQl query inside for loop

Tags: apex, query

I have the below code and  there is a SOQL query inside `for` loop. I have been instructed to avoid SOQL in the loop as these are invoked for every iteration of the loop. Since  i am a beginner in Salesforce i don't know how to implement that. Here's my code where i have advised to use Soql query and condition checking before `for` loop using a map.

```
if ((isTrgBefore && (isInsert||isUpdate ))){
   for( Item eachitem :newItemList ){
     if(eachItem.WhoId!=Null){
        Schema.SObjectType sobjectType = eachItem.WhoId.getSObjectType();
        String sobjectName = sobjectType.getDescribe().getName();
        if(sobjectName.equals(UTIL_Constants.SubString)){ 
                    List<Strategy> stg=[select Type from Strategy where Id=:eachItem.WhoId];
                        for(Strategy s:stg){
                            if(s.Type=='Market Strategy' || s.Type=='Market Potency'){
                            eachItem.Strategy__c = eachItem.WhoId; 
                            }
                        }
         }
     }
     setWhatIds.add(eachItem.WhatId);
  }
}
```

Please help
Thanks

Comment: Did you try walking through the logic of any of this canonical Q/A: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/321846/81648 or any of these answers?: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/372677/81648 | https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/293314/81648 | https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/327640/81648

Comment: Do that, then give an attempt yourself, then - if you are having trouble and can't get it to work - come back and [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/376676/edit) your question to update it by adding the code you have tried but that is not working correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the soql from loop, you would collect all the ids that you would want to use in where clause into a set, query the records once, build a map by id and within loop lookup the record and use it.

In the modified code below, look for comment 1, 2 and 3 for important bits.

```
if ((isTrgBefore && (isInsert||isUpdate ))){
    
    // 1. Collect ids from source list.
    Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();
    
    for(Item eachitem :newItemList) {    
        if (eachItem.WhoId != null) {
            ids.add(eachItem.id);
        }
    }
    
    // 2. Query all items at once and build a map by id
    Map<Id, Strategy> strategyById = new Map<Id, Strategy>([select Id, Type from Strategy where Id in :ids and (Type ='Market Strategy' or Type ='Market Potency')]);
    
    for( Item eachitem :newItemList ){

     if(eachItem.WhoId!=Null){

        Schema.SObjectType sobjectType = eachItem.WhoId.getSObjectType();
        String sobjectName = sobjectType.getDescribe().getName();

        if(sobjectName.equals(UTIL_Constants.SubString)){ 

            // 3. Get the record you looking for and use it
            Strategy s = strategyById.get(eachItem.whoId);
            if(s != null && (s.Type=='Market Strategy' || s.Type=='Market Potency')){
                eachItem.Strategy__c = eachItem.WhoId; 
            }
         }
     }

     setWhatIds.add(eachItem.WhatId);
  }
}
```

Comment: Strategy s = strategyById(eachItem.whoId);     strategyById-Method doesnot exist or incorrect signature.

Comment: Change to `Strategy s = strategyById.get(eachItem.whoId);` (note the `.get`)

Comment: The above code is not working and also i need to get the records matching criteria "Market Strategy " and "market Potency" before the for loop.can someone help?

Comment: You can add that condition to original query itself so it will only fetch if type is either Market Strategy or Potency. I have updated the answer